# help reading this schematic regarding high voltage coils

Tags: transformer, frequency, high-voltage, coil

This is the internal schematic for a high voltage coil used in old black&white televisions:

[image: schematic]

I want to use it in an arc generator and I want the maximum voltage gain. I know this is obtained by connecting the oscillator output to the least winded coil and the highest voltage will be between the pins of the coil with the highest wind.

But I have trouble understanding which is which. In other words, which pins must be connected to the oscillator output and between which pins will there be the maximum voltage?

here is the picture of the transformer: 
[image: real picture]

Comment: The numbers on the left are the numbers on the right.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I know that :)   In the schematic, which pins are those I want? I cant read schematics.

Comment: You need a lot more information. Either the turn counts for that transformer AND the schematic for the oscillator you propose to use, or the schematic for a TV that used that coil, or preferably all the above.

Answer (score 3):

Pins 1,2 for the primary, pin 7 to ground and the heavily insulated wire is the output is how I read it.

Be careful, those things hurt, and even the primary voltage will hurt a lot if you are running it in flyback mode.